# Can I use pytest.mark.skipif based on fixture parameter ID?

Tags: python, pytest, fixture

I have a fixture in my `conftest.py` file that has three parameters:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session",
        params=[(33, 303), (303, 3003), (3003, 300003)],
        ids=["small", "medium", "large"])
def complete(request):
    np.random.seed(1234567890)
    return np.random.rand(*request.param)
```

Now on a specific long running test function I would like to skip the "large" case.

```
@pytest.mark.skipif(...)
def test_snafu(complete):
    assert ...
```

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

its not clear what you are looking for

as of now, skip marker evaluation does not have access to test metadata
you might want to invoke `pytest.skip` inside the test function

Comment: This is indeed the way to go. I invoke `pytest.skip` inside the particular test cases based on the dimensions of the matrix. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it's possible. Just like shown below
I am skipping a certain param (using `skipif`)out of the 4 params with which I parameterized my fixture.

**And in the test execution, the skip really happens and all the tests in the calling test class will only execute for the first three params of the fixture and the fixture execution or processing will be skipped for the param that we marked as skip based on a certain condition to be satisfied.**

```
@pytest.fixture(
    scope='class',
    params=[
        conf.ACCOUNT_OWNER_ROLE,
        conf.ACCOUNT_READ_ONLY_ROLE,
        conf.ACCOUNT_ADMIN_ROLE,
        pytest.param(conf.PROJECT_USER_ROLE, marks=pytest.mark.skipif(
                environ.get('ENV_FOR_DYNACONF') == 'production',
                reason="This feature isn't yet released to production")
                         ),
    ],
    ids=[
        'Invitee has Account-owner role',
        'Invitee has Account-read-only role',
        'Invitee has Account-Admin role',
        'Invitee has Project-user role',
    ],
)
def my_rbac_root_fixture(
    request,
    spark_client_project_fix,
    spark_client_account_fix,
    spark_client_account_fix_invitee,
):
```

Let me know if you need more details on this @Midnighter

Comment: That's not quite what I'm looking for. You are skipping one parameter based on an environment variable. I would like to skip a specific parameter/test combination based on either using the the skipif decorator on the test or by using pytest.skip inside the test body based on the parameter id.